# How do you set background-color rgba on the body with background-image also?

Tags: html, css

How would I go about setting the rgba of the body along with a background image? I want the rgba to show up on top of the background image and stay there. A transparent color on top of the image Here is my css:

```
body{
 background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 background-size:cover;
 background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/zt6sfs21/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background):

```
Name:   background
Value:  [ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>
```

and

```
<final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box> || <'background-color'>
```

Just specify the background colour along with the other properties.

```
 background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

Comment: Seriously, how did you find the link to spec that fast?

Comment: color is seen flashing right when page loads and then disappears and the bg image is the only thing showing up

Comment: @Chipe, yeah that's how it works. I'm not sure what you are expecting?

Comment: yes, that's what you asked, and the answer is absolutely correct. If you want to know something else, you should rephrase your question

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I want the rgba of a color, just using this as an example (255, 0, 0, 0.5), To display ontop of the background image. Not just flash and then go away

Comment: @Chipe The MDN docs explain the behavior of background-size fairly well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size. For what you're describing, you need to specify [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds), which isn't supported in every browser.

Comment: @HashemQolami — I typed *CSS backgrounds and borders* into Google, that document has a good table of contents.

Answer (score 2):

ah, you weren't explaining yourself, I think what you're looking for is this:

add this **HTML** on top of your body:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

and then this **CSS**

```
body {
    background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Nelumno_nucifera_open_flower_-_botanic_garden_adelaide2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
.overlay {
    background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6yrse8uc/)

You could do the same applying a full background to the `body` and then using the image as a background for `.overlay` div, then apply an `opacity:0.5` property (or whatever). Of course this approach would apply for your situation were you're using full body width and height, but you could also use a `div` or whatever element with any size

Comment: I think you've added `left:0;` twice mistakenly.

Comment: Just a side-note: Specifying `width`/`height` of `100%` is pointless when the margin box of the absolutely positioned element is expanded by `top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;`. You could safely omit `width`/`height` in this case.

Comment: That does work! How about if I have content that eventually goes beyond the bottom of the window, such as in this example http://jsfiddle.net/6yrse8uc/1/

Comment: that will happen only in fiddle and such because of how it loads the content inside frames. But in real pages you won't have that issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want have an image overlaid color, you have to use another element to the fore.
Here is example:

CSS:

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Nelumno_nucifera_open_flower_-_botanic_garden_adelaide2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size:cover;
    margin:0;
    height:100%
}
.content{
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="content">
    [other elements]
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vv17uc16/

---

edit: yop, Fabio was first...